# How to bind a usercontrol to update value on a specific type of class

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, binding

I'm creating a usercontrol for editing an address class. The address class implements Inotifypropertychanged and has properties such as street, zip, code etc.

Then I have a customer class that holds an address class.

I want to create a usercontrol for editing address such that I bind the addresscontrol to the customer's address property. The address property should then be updated when I change the address in the user control.

```
<UIComponents:AddressControl  Address="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Address is a dependency property.
The property on the customer class also implements inotifypropertychanged, but the set is never called. I suspect that this is because the actual object isn't changed just a subproperty.

So how do I get it to call the setter when the object changes?

Regards
Morten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Customer class, hook the Address object's PropertyChanged event to a handler we'll call ReflectPropertyChanged.  ReflectPropertyChanged will call NotifyPropertyChanged on your Address member.

If you do this don't forget to implement a PropertyChanged handler in your Address dependency property that removes the handler from the old value when a new Address is set.

Comment: So basically I need to listen in the parent class for changes to the address class child property Address, and then do PropertyChanged(this, new...) on the Address property?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.  When a property change occurs in your Address object, you want to reflect that into a property change on your Address property in the Customer class.